# Installing vagrant plugin on windows XP

Tags: vagrant, berkshelf

I am trying to install vagrant-berkshelf plugin.
I have vagrant and ruby installed, I enter `vagrant plugin install vagrant-berkshelf`

and I get :
"An error occurred while installing json (1.8.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.1'` succeeds before bundling."

When I run `gem install json -v '1.8.1'`, it completes successfully.

It is not linked to berkshelf itself since I get the same error when I try some other plugins like vagrant-omnibus or vagrant-hostmanager.

I don't know what could be the problem, I don't know where to look at more logs or anything.
I had to deal with several errors to have vagrant running on windows XP, I don't know if it is even possible to install berkshelf on XP.
Can anyone help with this ?